# Sort Missing and Duplicate Ordinal Numbers Using IComparable

Tags: .net, vb.net, sorting, icomparable

I am tasked with writing code to use `IComparable` with our custom type (Product).

The Product type has a property called `OrdinalNumber` which is the property being compared for the sort operation.  An example of the ordinals can be something like this: 1 2 3 3 5 6 7 7 9 etc. The routine must replace duplicate or missing ordinals and sort the results.

I have found this example and have it working.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z(v=vs.110).aspx

Can someone please help me?

I don't want to sort a DataTable. We currently have code that sorts a DataTable, we want to rewrite that code to use a custom type called Product. The example code I have pasted here uses the new Product class.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class Product
    Implements IEquatable(Of Product)
    Implements IComparable(Of Product)
    Public Property ProductName() As String
        Get
            Return m_ProductName
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            m_ProductName = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ProductName As String

    Public Property ProductId() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_ProductId
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_ProductId = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_ProductId As Integer

    Public Property OrdinalNumber() As Integer
        Get
            Return m_OrdinalNumber
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            m_OrdinalNumber = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_OrdinalNumber As Integer

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return "Ordinal Number: " & OrdinalNumber & "   ID: " & ProductId & "   Name: " & ProductName
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function Equals(obj As Object) As Boolean
        If obj Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If
        Dim objAsProduct As Product = TryCast(obj, Product)
        If objAsProduct Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        Else
            Return Equals(objAsProduct)
        End If
    End Function

    Public Function SortByNameAscending(name1 As String, name2 As String) As Integer

        Return name1.CompareTo(name2)
    End Function

    Public Function CompareTo(compareProduct As Product) As Integer _
            Implements IComparable(Of Product).CompareTo

        If compareProduct Is Nothing Then
            Return 1
        Else

            Return Me.OrdinalNumber.CompareTo(compareProduct.OrdinalNumber)
        End If
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
        Return OrdinalNumber
    End Function

    Public Overloads Function Equals(other As Product) As Boolean Implements IEquatable(Of Product).Equals
        If other Is Nothing Then
            Return False
        End If
        Return (Me.OrdinalNumber.Equals(other.OrdinalNumber))
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: The first sentence says you want to sort a datatable, but there is no DataTable anywhere.  Is that a euphemism for Collection.  Why the need for that specific sort method?  `sorted = myProductsCollection.OrderBy(function (j) j.OrdinalNumber)` should give you what you want with much less code

Comment: No, I say my legacy code sorts a DataTable currently.  We want to replace that old code with something more elegant.  Read again please.

Comment: if you want to sort a `System.Data.DataTable`, whats the point of the Product class and that code?  Your question just isnt very clear.

Comment: i just did a quick test and Selection ("Bingo") Sort is many, many times slower than using `OrderBy` (1.6 secs vs 3ms on 10k elements)

Comment: You're not reading my post - or maybe you just don't understand...I don't want to sort a DataTable.  We currently have code that sorts a DataTable, we want to rewrite that code to use a custom type called Product.  The example code I have pasted here uses the new Product class.  I only mentioned the old code for reference, context.

Comment: I do appreciate your help though and would like to know how a bingo sort is any different than the OrderBy you mention in your comment.

Comment: I *did* read the question and no I dont understand - thats what comments are for.  `...my legacy code sorts a DataTable currently. We want to replace that old code with...`  Sure sounds like you want to sort a DT.  With the interfaces mentioned though, all you do is supply the comparer; NET supplies the actual sort mechanism.  So its also unclear why you need that sorter or how you need to plan to use it in place of List.Sort.

Comment: How would I implement a selection or "bingo" sort using List.Sort?

Comment: My turn! As I said, NET supplies the Sort algorithm, you just supply the comparer [read the comment again, you dont understand].  Another test still with 10k items, `List.Sort()` with a comparer you write is only a little slower than `OrderBy` (3 vs 20 vs 1600 ms).  If you absolutely need SelectionSort, you have to write it yourself.

Comment: How many items are you sorting?  Because Selection sort scales very badly.  With 20k items it takes 6600 ms!  (vs 5 and 35 ms).  Yes, it only adds clarity/is helpful when you say it, right?

Comment: I cant help because you are asking for nonsense things.  Using `List.Sort()` **NET** provides the sort algorithm.  You cant use it with your own Sorter.  You **can** write your own Sort method using `SelectionSort` at which point, you probably dont need a comparer.  The first comment gave you an easy way to sort `Products` very very quickly.  As noted, SelectionSort is suboptimal for more than a few things.

Comment: I don't want to just sort the ordinal numbers, sometimes the ordinal numbers will be duplicates or missing for example 1 2 3 3 5 6 7...how would you handle that scenario?  I thought the selection, insertion or bingo sort would help...maybe not?  I need to change those ordinal numbers where they are missing or duplicates so that I end up with 1 2 3 4 5 6 7.  Sorry I'm not a sorting guru like you.

Comment: Missing numbers wont matter 3 is still less than 5.  Whats the tie breaker for duplicates, the name?  In that case, you would want to use a Comparer to supply that logic, but the built in sorters would work just fine.

Comment: I was just reading your answer when you deleted it...can you put it back it appeared to be very informative.

Comment: The sort is for handling items in a ListView that have been rearranged using drag and drop.  I send them to the server to be adjusted and sorted, if that helps at all.

Comment: I am double checking something.  It doesnt really answer the question as posted with a Bingo sort and the one I threw together is leaving the second to last item untouched at the bottom. Hmmm - for a ListView you need a ListViewSorter which is a different beast along with conversions from string.  So what I had wont do you much good - I thought you were sorting a `List(Of Product)`?

Comment: I am, just ignore the ListView part, I send the items back to the server as a List(Of Product).

Comment: What you had there looked like a really good start...hope you will help me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why there is such focus on the Bingo variation (now redacted via edit) of a [`SelectionSort`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort).  The Bingo version is slightly faster version of SelectionSort when there are *many* duplicate values but only marginally so.  It is not a sorter specialized for cases when there are some dupes.  They are both slow.

`How would I implement a selection or "bingo" sort using List.Sort`
Thats not how it works.  The actual sort mechanism(s) is built into the NET Framework.  In the case of `List.Sort()` it will select one of 3 sorts as it sees fit.  You *can* supply the comparison mechanism.

Given a data set of `{1,3,5,5,7,9,15}` The elements with `1` and `3` will always sort lower than `5` or `1024`, so missing elements are not an issue.  How you want the duplicate values to compare, might be.

There are several alternatives:

#### Linq's OrderBy

```
Dim sortedProds = myProducts.OrderBy(Function (j) j.Ordinal).ToList()
```

Time: **~6 ms** for 20k items
If you want to do something about dupes, such as sort *them* by the Id:

```
Dim ProdsL = myProducts.OrderBy(Function(j) j.Ordinal).
                   ThenBy(Function(k) k.Id).ToList()
```

Time: **~8 ms** for 20k items

### List.Sort using a comparer

Make the class implement `IComparable`:

```
Public Function CompareTo(other As ProductItem) As Integer _ 
                         Implements IComparable(Of ProductItem).CompareTo
    If Ordinal < other.Ordinal Then Return -1
    If Ordinal > other.Ordinal Then Return 1

    ' equal, return the lower ID or:
    'Return 0

    If Id < other.Id Then Return -1
    Return 1
End Function
```

Usage:

```
myProducts.Sort(Function(x, y) x.CompareTo(y))
```

Time: **~28 ms** for 20k items

You can also use a method which performs the comparison which means you dont have to implement `IComparable` unless it has value in other cases.

```
Private Function ProductComparer(x As ProductItem, y As ProductItem) As Integer
    If x.Ordinal < y.Ordinal Then Return -1
    If x.Ordinal > y.Ordinal Then Return 1

    ' equal, return the lower ID or:
    'Return 0

    If x.Id < y.Id Then Return -1
    Return 1
End Function
```

Usage:

```
myProducts.Sort(AddressOf ProductComparer)
```

Time: **11 ms**

### Bingo Sort

`SelectionSort` (~3650 ms) and the `Bingo` variation (~3590 ms) are so far behind the others, they do not seem worth considering.  Bingo is included just to satisfy the *original* question (even though there is already one in use elsewhere).

```
  Private Sub BingoSort(items As List(Of ProductItem))
    ' converted from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort#Variants
    ' for http://stackoverflow.com/q/42303395/1070452

    Dim max As Int32 = items.Count - 1
    Dim nextVal = items(max).Ordinal
    Dim value As Int32
    Dim tmp As ProductItem

    For i As Int32 = max - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If items(i).Ordinal > nextVal Then
            nextVal = items(i).Ordinal
        End If
    Next
    While (max > 0) And (items(max).Ordinal = nextVal)
        max -= 1
    End While
    While (max > 0)
        value = nextVal
        nextVal = items(max).Ordinal
        For i As Int32 = max - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If items(i).Ordinal = value Then
                tmp = items(i)
                items(i) = items(max)
                items(max) = tmp
                max -= 1
            ElseIf items(i).Ordinal > nextVal Then
                nextVal = items(i).Ordinal
            End If
        Next
        While (max > 0) And (items(max).Ordinal = nextVal)
            max -= 1
        End While
    End While
End Sub
```

Usage:

```
BingoSort(myProducts)
```

Time: **~3590 ms** for 20k items.

Note that when there are no dupes (or the original list starts in `Id` order), the result is the same as linq's `OrderBy`

```
Dim Valid = ProdsLinq.SequenceEqual(ProdsBingo)
```

Given the poor performance there doesn't seem to be a reason to use it here.  `IComparable` lets you decide how to tie-break duplicates and both Linq and `List.Sort(IComparable)` are gobs and gobs faster.

Note that something similar exists for the `DataTable`:

```
myDT.DefaultView.Sort = "Ordinal ASC"
' or
myDT.DefaultView.Sort = "Ordinal ASC, Id ASC"
```

Comment: This is such a great answer.  Thank you very much.  How/where would I put code to replace/change the ordinal number if there was a duplicate?  So, 1 2 3 3 5 6 6 8 would output to 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8?

Comment: It should be easy to put them in order, then change the Ordinal value in a loop.